# update datetime with null value in mysql by php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to update my datatime field to NULL,
php version 7.3.7

```
    if($_POST['value']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
      $timestamp=NULL;
    }else {
      $dateTime = $_POST['value'];
      $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($_POST['value']));
   }
$query="update forms set $_POST[limitInputField]='$timestamp' where  formid='$_POST[formId]'";
$result=$dbCnn->query($query)or die($dbCnn->error);
```

it gives error when $timestamp is null:

> Incorrect datetime value: '' for column farsifor_m.forms.enddate at row 1

But when I quote "NULL" and remove quotations around $timestamp in the query, if
$timestamp is null it works properly but if $timestamp value is not null it gives error.

```
   if($_POST['value']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
     $timestamp="NULL";
   }else {
     $dateTime = $_POST['value'];
     $timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($_POST['value']));
   }
  $query="update forms set $_POST[limitInputField]=$timestamp where       formid='$_POST[formId]'";
    $result=$dbCnn->query($query)or die($dbCnn->error);
```

Comment: Use prepared statements. NULL is not the same as an empty string, so it's erroring out. Using prepared statements bypasses this issue. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: is there any way else? my codes work properly in php 5.6. but not in 7.3.7

Comment: In mysql u can use now() function

Comment: I'm surprised it works in 5.6. Prepared statements and parameter binding is the safest way to pass data into SQL queries, and prevents a ton of headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to use prepared statements; and do not inject post variables to "build" the query. Having said that:

You can use [`NULLIF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) for convenience. In the following example the specific value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` will be converted to NULL:

```
UPDATE forms SET col = NULLIF(:timestamp, '0000-00-00 00:00:00') WHERE formid = :formid
```

Or you can simply:

```
UPDATE forms SET col = :timestamp WHERE formid = :formid
```

And use PHP to pass a variable containing string or [`null`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php).

Comment: how to use this kind of query in prapare statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this with some slight changes to your code (take note of single and double quotes):

```
    if($_POST['value']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
      $timestamp="NULL";
    }else {
      $dateTime = $_POST['value'];
      $timestamp = "'".date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($_POST['value']))."'";
   }
$query="update forms set $_POST[limitInputField]=$timestamp where  formid='$_POST[formId]'";
```

This way if you're setting a NULL value in timestamp the query would look something like this:

```
update forms set limitInputField=NULL where formid='123'
```

But if you're putting a value in there it would look like this:

```
update forms set limitInputField='2019-09-03 17:08' where formid='123'
```

Important to note there are no quotes around the NULL when setting the value, but there are around the date.

Comment: This answer may be downvoted since you left SQL Injections vulnerabilities.

Comment: I'm just basing this on his code for ease of understanding. Also - it would have to be a damn clever hacker to get SQL injection working through that date function. :P (But thanks for pointing that out. I'm new to contributing here.)

Comment: What about `$_POST[limitInputField]` ? `$_POST[formId]` ? Always use prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = $_POST['Date']; //get date from form
$time = $_POST['Time']; //get time from form

if(strtotime($date.$time)==0){ // check if null or not 
    $AboutDate = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"; 
}else{                        
    $AboutDate = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($date.$time)); 
}
```

> Then Update/Insert into SQL

```
UPDATE xxx(table) SET xxx(column) = NULLIF('$AboutDate','0000-00-00 00:00:00') WHERE xxxx = xxxxx
```

> Let's go BABY